# An algebra with no two-sided ideal has only one irreducible representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose an algebra has no sided ideal. Then why does it have only one irreducible representation upto isomorphism?

Comment: You want your algebra to be simple *and* artinian for this to happen. The simple left artinian rings are precisely those rings that admit one isomorphism class of simple modules, and in particular any minimal ideal is a representative of this isomorphism class.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff interesting, I didn't know that such a ring was necessarily artinian. Would you be so kind as to point me to where i could find the result? Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb The Weyl algebra $A_1(k)$ is a simple ring over zero characteristic, but it is not artinian.

Comment: Dear @PedroTamaroff there is some misunderstanding apparently. Again, I'm asking  "why does one isoclass of simple module imply artinian?" That is entailed by your claim in the first comment. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, I meant to say the *semisimple* rings that admit exacly one isomorphism class of simple modules are precisely the simple artinian rings.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff ok, that clears things up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting "no two sided ideal" as meaning that the ring only has trivial two-sided ideals.

In fact, the statement is false for rings in general. If you take the endomorphism ring of an infinite dimensional vector space, then its quotient by its unique maximal two-sided ideal, you get a simple, nonNoetherian Von Neumann regular ring. It has maximal right ideals which are direct summands and maximal right ideals which are essential right ideals, and the two quotients give rise to nonisomorphic simple modules.

As Pedro has brought up in the comments, the problem is fine if the ring is artinian, and this will be the case of the ring has a minimal right ideal, or if the algebra is finite dimensional. In that case it is a semisimple ring.

To prove a simple artinian ring has only one type of right ideal, first show that any simple right module is isomorphic to a minimal right ideal. Then work to show that two nonisomorphic minimal right ideals annihilate each other. Draw a conclusion that this cannot occur in a simple ring, so there is really only one isotype.