# Artin-Wedderburn theorem and representation theory

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

How to apply the Artin-Weddernburn theorem to representation theory? The Artin-Weddeburn theorem says that if $R$ is finite dimensional $k$ algebra( where $k$ is an algeraically closed field), then $R=M_{n_1}(k)\bigoplus\dots\bigoplus M_{n_r}(k)$ for some $r$ and $n_i$. OTOH, we know from Maschke's theorem that if $G$ is a finite group and char$(k)\nmid|G|$, $k[G]$ is semisimple. So we can write $k[G]=M_{n_1}(k)\bigoplus\dots\bigoplus M_{n_r}(k)$. Then can we get any information about the $k$ linear representation of $G$ from this decomposition? For example, can we conclude that the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $G$ are $n_1,\dots,n_r$ and the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ is $r$? Can we apply a-w theorem to representation theory if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Isn't it important to discover that every representation for a finite dimensional $k$ algebra is isomorphic to a direct sum of irreducible representations?  To me that seems to be the chief thing you get.

Comment: Neither the Artin-Wedderburn theorem nor Maschke's theorem refers to the field being algebraically closed.  It's just that when it is algebraically closed, the structure of the resulting product ring is simpler (the matrix rings are all over the field instead of extensions of the field.)

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain further how should I correspond the decomposition of $k[G]$ to the decomposition of represention of $G$?

Comment: Each matrix ring provides exactly one isotype of irreducible representation.  The decomposition of the representation of $G$ will depend entirely on $G$. The decomposition of $G$ could contain any or all of the irreducible representations, in different multiplicities.

Comment: well, how can i see that each $M_{n_i}(k)$ provides an irre repre of $G$ (and they are exactly \bold{all} the irre repre of $G$ without using dimension argument)?

Comment: I outlined the case for simple artinian rings [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1496255/29335) and then the rest follows from the characterization of maximal right ideals of a product ring.

Comment: Thanks! May be we can take $V_i=k^{n_i}$ as the irre vector space and $g$ acts on $V_i$ as $\pi_i(g)$ acts on $V_i$, where $\pi_i(g)$ is the component of $g$ in $M_{n_i}(k)$.

Comment: Yes, those work